# How to convert nested arrays into one-dimensional?

Tags: ruby

Here i have nested arrays with multidimensional so how to get  arrays into one dimensional!

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[[1,25],[9,0]],[[[21,2],[22,5]],"ruby",[58,96]]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,25],[9,0],[21,2],[22,5],"ruby",[58,96]]
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: @JörgWMittag actually i don't have the code to write due to nested. so i put the usecase.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what you have tried and explain why that didn't work. This saves answerers from wasting their time answering things that you have already tried and explaining things you already know. What did you try? What didn't work? How didn't it work? What did you try to fix it? What research have you done? What were the results of that research? Why are those results unsatisfactory to you? Which parts of the Ruby documentation are unclear to you?

Comment: @JörgWMittag sure from next time i will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple implementation of what you're trying to achieve. I believe that this can be improved furthermore.

```rb
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[[1,25],[9,0]],[[[21,2],[22,5]],"ruby",[58,96]]]
print(x, "\n")

def depth (a)
  return 0 unless a.is_a?(Array)
  return 1 + depth(a[0])
end

def custom_map (list)
    temp = []
    for i in list
        if depth(i) == 1
            temp.append(i)
        elsif depth(i) > 1
            temp.push(*custom_map(i))
        else i.is_a? String
            temp.append(i)
        end
    end
    return temp
end

y = custom_map(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a answer

Comment: Yes what ever you said its correct, but the thing is i don't know how to deal with nested arrays. so i put it in a simple way that is the use case

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the desired result by using recursion.

```
def recursive_flatten(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |e,a|
    if e.is_a?(Array)
      if e.flatten == e
        a << e
      else
        a.concat(recursive_flatten(e))
      end
    else
      a << e
    end
  end
end
```

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[[1,25],[9,0]],[[[21,2],[22,5]],"ruby",[58,96]]]
```

```
recursive_flatten(arr)
  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 25], [9, 0], [21, 2], [22, 5], "ruby", [58, 96]]
```